# Laravel 5 - Decrypt Crypt::encrypt in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, cryptojs

I'm using `Crypt::encrypt` to encrypt my data and feed to Javascript code. How can I decrypt the data in Javascript?

Comment: Why would you do that in the first place?

Comment: Find out all the [characteristics of the encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31734468/1816580) before you can try to replicate it.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I create a javascript game and I want to send protected data to front end in order to avoid modifying by users.

Comment: Even if you send it encrypted then you must also provide decryption key to the Javascript in order to decrypt that so if users want to they will be able to decrypt the data. You should do all the checks on the server side

Comment: @ArtjomB. OK, Thank you a lot :)

Comment: What @jedrzej.kurylo is trying to say is that [Javascript Cryptography Considered Harmful](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/)

Comment: Although this totally doesn't make sense as an actual encryption layer (because all of the information to decrypt the information is there in the browser), this is exactly what I was looking for to enable a layer of obscurity for some sensitive information.

Answer (score 9):

Using laravel 5.1 and CryptoJS which can be found at (https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/).

in .env set:

1. APP_KEY=uberkeythatrocks

in config/app.php set:

2. 'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC'

in MyController.php:

3. $mySecret = "Something I wanna hide from them";
4. $encrypted = Crypt::encrypt($mySecret);

in index.js:

5. var key = "uberkeythatrocks";
6. var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key);
7. var readable = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

IMPORTANT:
The 'key' in PHP must be the same with 'key' in JS and the 'cipher' in PHP must be the same in JS however, CryptoJS will automatically select either AES-128-CBC or AES-256-CBC depending on the length of your 'key'. Although laravel 5.1 default 'cipher' is AES-256-CBC so I would suggest you get your 'key' from .env file to use in JS.

To change or generate a new 'key' from Laravel

1. C:/mylaravel> php artisan key:generate [enter]

To use AES-128-CBC

1. Edit config/app.php and set 'cipher' => 'AES-128-CBC'

then

2. C:/mylaravel> php artisan key:generate [enter]

NOTE that the change of 'key' will mean that an existing user account login password will not work unless you delete the user and then create new.

HOPE THIS HELPS! :)

Comment: Is there a way to do it other way round, encrypt in JS and decrypt in Laravel 5.1? I tried but I keep getting `DecryptException in BaseEncrypter.php line 45:The payload is invalid.`

Comment: Well I got help from https://github.com/brainfoolong/cryptojs-aes-php. This is sample code to use cryptjs with Laravel, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: what is the file that should be taken from the https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

Comment: Why am I getting an <empty string> when logging readable var which I expected to give me the string I encrypt?

Answer (score 4):

### CryptoJs and Laravel 6 & 7.x

Place a Mix variable inside **.env** file

```
MIX_APP_KEY=${APP_KEY}
```

See: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#environment-variables

In **/resources/assets/js/app.js** add:

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

window.decrypt = (encrypted) => {
    let key = process.env.MIX_APP_KEY.substr(7);
    var encrypted_json = JSON.parse(atob(encrypted));
    return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted_json.value, CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key), {
        iv : CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted_json.iv)
    }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
};
```

And finally somewhere in your script you can decrypt like so:

```
console.log(decrypt(encrypted_text));
```

Comment: say I WILL NOT EXPOSE MY APP_KEY TO THE PUBLIC 100 times.

Comment: is there anyway to do this without using APP_KEY of laravel?

Answer (score 2):

**I SOLVE THIS:**

I'm using Laravel Framework 5.7.28 and i want to decrypt some users passwords in my node.js application

For Decrypt in my Js file i include [CryptoJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) and [Base64 JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-base64)


Here is the code:

> **$key** is the APP_KEY that you have in your .env file 
>   **$encrypted** is what you encrypt with the **Crypt::encrypt** in laravel

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
var Base64 = require('js-base64').Base64;


var encrypted = '{{ $encrypted }}';
var key = "{{ $key }}";

var encrypted_json = JSON.parse(Base64.decode(encrypted));


// Now I try to decrypt it.
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted_json.value, CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key), {
       iv : CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted_json.iv)
});

console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

Comment: You can use native `atob` function instead of requiring 'js-base64' package.

And make sure that you remove the `base64:` prefix from the laravel key.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above didn't work for me. So I tried to encrypt the string **"1234"** on **Laravel 8** and then decrypt it on **Node.js**.

My actual use case is that we set our OAuth2 access token as an encrypted cookie on Laravel 8. Then our client sends HTTP-requests to a Node.js backend (microservice architecture). To validate the JWT token, the Node.js backend needs to decrypt the (Laravel)-encrypted access token first.

### ENCRYPT (Laravel 8):

Open any Controller and add the following code in a function:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

return Crypt::encrypt("1234");
```

**If you now open the route, which is linked to the controller method, you get the encrypted string of "1234".**

### DECRYPT (Node.js)

Please make sure to install **crypto-js** first (https://github.com/brix/crypto-js).

**Do the following steps before you run the code:**

1. Replace **"your_string_to_decrypt"** by the encrypted "1234" string (you retrieved from Laravel before)
2. Replace **"your_laravel_app_key"** with your **Laravel APP_KEY** from your .env **(remove the "base64:" part !)**
3. Important to know: Your encryption cipher-method in Laravel is defined in **config/app.php**. The default is **"AES-256-CBC"**. Crypto-Js automatically selects the right AES-cipher depending on the length of your specified key. After removing "base64:" your key should have 44 characters for using "AES-256-CBC". ([https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45318/how-long-in-letters-are-encryption-keys-for-aes#:~:text=An%20AES%20128%2Dbit%20key,hexadecimal%20string%20with%2032%20characters.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45318/how-long-in-letters-are-encryption-keys-for-aes#:%7E:text=An%20AES%20128%2Dbit%20key,hexadecimal%20string%20with%2032%20characters.))

> CryptoJS supports AES-128, AES-192, and AES-256. It will pick the variant by the size of the key you pass in. If you use a passphrase, then it will generate a 256-bit key.
> https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#ciphers

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

let payload = "your_string_to_decrypt"
let key = "your_laravel_app_key"

let encryptStr = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(payload);
let encryptData = encryptStr.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
encryptData = JSON.parse(encryptData);
let iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encryptData.iv);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptData.value,  CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key), {
    iv : iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
decrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decrypted);

console.log(decrypted)
```

Finally you are done and the Node.js log shows "1234".

(Of course this is not the best code, but it shows the functionality).

### References:

Node.js code: https://gist.github.com/huzemin/e8d7a904cec55d4d7635c9322f143c42