# Can 2 parties agree on using AES, and only share the private key?

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes

I'm a bit confused as to the various implementations of AES that I find online.

If 2 companies are sending and receiving files, and they both agree to use AES and they share a private key, is that enough for things to work correctly?

When I view sample code online, I notice that some people:

- have a private key
- some use hmac, some don't
- some randomly generate a IV, some use a fixed IV.

If you read a spec that the ONLY thing shared between company A and company B is a single private key, how could this ever work?  i.e. company A sends an encrypted message to company B, and company B has to decrypt it.

If the only data shared is a private key, is that enough?

Do you need to share the salt/IV?  Is Salt/IV the same thing?

Comment: They *also* need to agree on a container format.

Comment: I extended my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734161/aes-encryption-using-c-sharp-and-decryption-in-java), so this question should be answered there. *"Is Salt/IV the same thing?"* **No** *"Do you need to share the salt/IV?"* **Not** if you derive the IV also from the password+salt by requesting a larger output size. In that case you only need to add the salt.

Comment: A "private key" is normally used for asymmetric cryptography (having a public and a private key). For symmetric encryption the right name is "secret key".

Answer (score 1):

Sharing the private key at the outset will be sufficient.

When you send your data, you should send the IV alongside the data. You should never reuse the same IV for different transmissions, as that opens you up to certain cryptoanalysis attacks - however, the IV is not a cryptographic secret, so you can send it alongside the data.

Comment: When they decrypt, how will they know if the IV is sent alongside or not?  Meaning appended to the encrypted message?

Comment: @coolbreeze You would send it in some sort of data structure inside of the same message that contains the encrypted data.

Comment: Do they salts have to be the same or encryption can use one salt, and decryption another? e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769741/Csharp-AES-bits-Encryption-Library-with-Salt

Comment: @coolbreeze Salts are only used if you're going to hash some sort of shared value that's not the same size as the key. If you're sharing the key itself, how it was derived makes no difference, and there's no need to share it. (Unless you're using salts in the place of IV to derive new keys every time, but please don't do that). Just share the derived key and change IVs every time that you communicate and pass it alongside the message.

Comment: do you have a c# example of that?

Comment: @coolbreeze I can probably come up with a dozen container formats and ways to send them in the course of an hour or two, but, the better question is, how do you intend to send the data? Post to a web service, communication over a server port, email...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88213/discussion-between-willaien-and-cool-breeze).

Comment: Probably you guys resolved this in chat, but yeah I think one of the most common ways -- but certainly not the only possible way -- is to append the IV as plaintext to the beginning of each message. The sender knows those 16 bytes are for the IV and so does the receiver.  No confusion.  It is cryptographically secure to do this, to advertise your IVs in the New York Times, or to hand them to your worst enemy. Some will say it is not, but it is.  If the IV were XORd to the cipher text, it would be useless. But it is XORd to the plaintext before encryption. An enemy who knows this is still lost.

Comment: Although the answer is not incorrect, it is insufficient to explain the questions. Besides that, the question is already flagged as dupe.